# Accessing SVN or Remote Git Repositories etc using iOS or c/c++

Tags: c++, ios, git, svn

I was wondering if there are any libraries available for iOS (or c/c++ for that matter) that will allow one to write an app that can access git repositories. Things like accessing files, committing, and uploading the files.

I wrote a syntax highlighted text editor for iOS, and now that Apple seems to be blocking any new apps that use dropbox, I'm thinking it's about time to make it work with svn/git, but since I use git more than svn it might be worth checking out these first.

So yeah, any libraries available for accessing git/svn repositories conveniently?

Answer (score 1):

How about [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/)?
It is not fully feature complete but I guess it worth to look at.